Where does the factor $1/3$ in the wave metric come from?
In P.T. Chrusciel's "Elements of General Relativity" (Birkhäuser 2020) there is the following calculation:
The linearized Einstein Field equations can, after a suitable choice of coordinates, be written as
$$
\square\hbar_{\mu\nu} = \square\left(h_{\mu\nu} - \frac{h}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}\right) = -16\pi T_{\mu\nu}
$$
Where $h^{\mu\nu}$ is a small correction to the flat metric, and $\hbar^{\mu\nu}$ is the trace-reversed correction. We can solve this equation using the Green's function for the d'Alembertian, which, in the far-field regime (Distance to mass distribution is far greater than the extent of the mass distribution), can be approximated as
$$
\hbar_{\mu\nu}\approx \frac{4}{|\vec x|}\int_{\Bbb R^3}T_{\mu\nu}(t-|\vec x|,\vec y)d\vec y
$$
Since the energy-momentum tensor fulfills a the divergence identity $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0$, it follows from the above that
$$
\hbar_{ij}\approx \frac{2}{|\vec x|}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\int_{\Bbb R^3}T_{00}(t-|\vec x|,\vec y)y^iy^jd\vec y
$$
Here $i,j$ denote spatial indices, and their position does not really matter since they are raised and lowered with the Minkowski metric, which acts as the identity on the spatial part of a four-vector. The above is easily shown from a direct calculation, which will not be repeated here. We now recognize the quadrupole moment
$$
q_{ij}(t) = \int_{\Bbb R^3}T_{00}(t,\vec y)y^iy^jd\vec y
$$
In terms of which I would think it reasonable to write the spatial part of the trace-reversed correction as
$$
\hbar_{ij} = \frac{2}{|\vec x|}\ddot q_{ij}(t-|\vec x|)
$$
However, Chrusciel states this with an additional factor of $1/3$:
$$
\hbar_{ij} = \frac{2}{3|\vec x|}\ddot q_{ij}(t-|\vec x|)
$$
Where does it come from?

Most likely it's that the quadrupole moment is defined with an additional factor of 3.  Conventions for the definitions of the quadrupole moment differ from reference to reference.

Everything above comes from the same reference.

Can you edit your question to indicate that. At the moment it reads like you are asking for an explanation of a differing result that you have obtained. In particular, I don't recognise your definition of $q$.

@paulina Do you mean that the two equations with and without the factor of $3$ both came from the same reference?

@LeeMosher that is indeed the case. Only the equation for $\hbar_{ij}$ without the factor $1/3$ was added by me.

@paulina helpful tip, you can use the ">" markdown directive before cited parts of your post, to help clarify they are citations.

There is no universally adopted definition of the trace-free quadrupole tensor. The two most commonly adopted forms differ by a factor of 3, as you have found.
It would be unfortunate though if a single text had used both definitions.
e.g. see here.
